# Using JavaFX, how can I get app to play sound from local file instead of URI?

Tags: audio, javafx, javafx-8

I'm having an issue getting my app to play a sound from a local file instead of a web URI, i know the parameter for AudioFile is a URI but i don't know how to obtain my file location in URI format? This is my code:

http://gyazo.com/9419d3afe78f9c8fd4c02a0c3c000a5e

As you can see, I'm using a link for the audio clips but i would like to replace that link with the local file location for the mp3. For example, the "dang.mp3" file i have in my images package to the left.  How can i convert the location to a usable URI to pass as a parameter for my AudioFile ? As it stands, since I'm using links to be played by the app, a current problem i'm having is that once the links to said mp3 files expire, my application breaks because it cannot load the files since they don't exist anymore, which is why i just wanna include the files locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the [AudioClip](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/AudioClip.html) Constructor API documentation:

> URL string from which to load the audio clip. This can be an HTTP, file or jar source.

So we can just do this:

```
new AudioClip(TestClass.class.getResource("test.mp3").toExternalForm());
```

to obtain an AudioClip instance pointing to "test.mp3" residing next to the TestClass.

Comment: yes right after i asked this i figured what i was doing wrong. It doesnt take a URI parameter it takes a String parameter thus i just had to add toString to the end of my URI call. What you posted works perfect if i have the file in the same package as my controller class. Thanks so much :)